# Android: Can Android 7.0 OS cancel network requests made by the app in, in doze mode

Tags: android, retrofit, android-doze

I have an Android app and I seeing this particular pattern in the network calls made by my app. The device send http requests properly when an app is started. But after sometime, I start seeing lot  java.io.IOException: Canceled in the logs. I am not unsubscribing from these retrofit calls and neither I am cancelling them in the code.

Is it possible, that the Android 7.0 doze off mode can actually cancel network requests?

Thanks in advance.

Please give reason on downvoting so that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible, that the Android 7.0 doze off mode can actually cancel network requests?

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_doze): "In Doze mode, the system attempts to conserve battery by restricting apps' access to network and CPU-intensive services. **It also prevents apps from accessing the network** and defers their jobs, syncs, and standard alarms. " (emphasis added)

Note that Doze mode was added in Android 6.0.